# How to replace a taxonomy term by its description?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

In drupal 7.39, I have created a taxonomy vocabulary called **TYPE**. Inside this vocabulary I have added list of terms called **CLOSE**, **END** and **INITIAL**.

By default, when I view the node page it will show the Taxonomy term as **CLOSE**, **END**. But I don't want this, instead of the **CLOSE** term it should be replaced with the description specified in the **CLOSE** term.

Any suggestions about how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement using view. In view configuration, add relationship to "Content: Taxonomy terms on node", then add "Taxonomy term: Term description (Term description)" field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Nikhil. But still i'm not getting it.

Comment: First create view of your content type[which using TYPE vocabulary], then go to advance link at right side of view. Add relationship to "Content: Taxonomy terms on node" fields and select TYPE vocabulary in configuration. Then add "Content: Taxonomy terms on node" into fields section.

Comment: Ya I got. But that description is not generated as term link. I got that as plain text.

Comment: Go to "REWRITE RESULTS" under Taxonomy term: Term description field, then select 'Output this field as a link' and then provide link path.

Comment: Sorry for the interruption. I have got the link, but when the content has CLOSE term it will redirect to Tags/CLOSE, if the content has END term it will redirect to Tags/END. How to do this?

Comment: Add "Taxonomy term: Term ID" and make it exclude from display. Inside Taxonomy term: Term description field configuration provide  "taxonomy/term/[tid]" as a link path.

Comment: "Taxonomy term: Term ID" added in Fields, the path in  "Taxonomy term: Term description " didn't fetch the [tid].

Comment: Please rearrange the fields order i.e.  
"Taxonomy term: Term ID" field should be before "Taxonomy term: Term description". Once it work please mark this answer as solved.

Comment: Hi @nikhil... Is there any way to achieve this programatically

Comment: I've created a view page with results for type and a included filter. This works fine for single tags(terms), but as soon as a content type has multiple terms, the results get messed up.   
now it display a result row for each term replaced and no longer list the terms as comma delimited. - When I flag 'Use aggregation' and 'Query settings'-Distinct, it does drop the multiple rows for each content item, but it only list the one and first term and doesn't put them all in line. -- Is there something else to be done to make it behave the same for multiple tags?

Comment: Select "Allow multiple values" for contextual filter field configuration under More section.